# Finding a Regular Expression for an Intersection of Two Regular Expressions

Tags: regular-expressions, closure-properties

Finding a Regular Expression for an Intersection of Two Regular Expressions

PAIR of regular expressions is ((ss*)t*) and ((ss*) + (tt*)).

How do I find a regular expression that represents the intersection of the languages defined by the pair?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: go via automata; all constructions are in the book resp. given in lecture (probably).

Comment: Think about it like this: are there any words in first language which begin with $t$? - if not, you can throw away the $tt^*$ from the second expression. Now, you have two very similar expressions: $ss^*t^*$ and $ss^*$ - from here the answer should be obvious ;) PS. The parenthesis in your question are suspiciously extraneous. Are you sure you've copied the question correctly?

Comment: can't you just use the AND operator?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry In the context of theoretical computer science, regular expressions have only concatenation, OR and *. Adding AND wouldn't change the power of the system but, by convention, it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you can convert both expressions to NFAs, then construct a NFA that is the intersection of both NFAs. From this NFA, convert it into a GNFA and from the GNFA convert it on the regular expression, the result is the intersection of both expressions.

Comment: For people reading who do not know what an **NFA** is, it is a [Nondeterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). Additionally, a **GNFA** is [Generalized Nondeterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_nondeterministic_finite_automaton)